# When I resize my browser my content falls outside of my header how can I stop this?

Tags: html, css

I have my h1 inside my header and I would like to know how to get my header to respond and resize when I resize my browser so the content does not spill over the header. I am completely okay with redoing my code if it solves my problem.

```css
#header {
    max-height:110px;
    background-color: darkorange;
    border: 1px solid burlywood;
    border-bottom:  1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1> Guide to Painting:A guide to getting your painting projects done efficiently and quickly!</h1>
```

Comment: You probably need to remove the `max-height`, resize the content in the header so it fits, or apply `overflow: hidden` but you need to reproduce the behavior for us with a demo, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Could you please add your html too?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: Check setting a viewport size -> H1 as any other item using font can use font: your_font 4vw or any number to match your needs

Comment: The "Guide to Painting:A guide to getting your painting projects done..." was the html but it did not show up like I had planned. This was my second question and I am still figuring this out. The answer below fixed my problem and I appreciate everyone's response.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by "falls outside the browser" the solution might be to  swap max-height for min-height.

```css
#header {
  min-height: 110px;
  background-color: darkorange;
  border: 1px solid burlywood;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>
    This is a long text might overflows to the right if the window is narrow
  </h1>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8jnofysv/

Unfortunately your problem statement is vague and could mean a number of things, my specific solution would solve only one of those

Comment: Changing max-height: To min-height: was the exact answer I needed. My text now stays with-in my header when I resize it.

Comment: Glad to help @MichaelDiffey, thank me by marking the answer as correct with the check

Comment: I marked it a good answer but I am still a noob so it won't show up until I have more reputation.